# Why is executing "select * from dbc.columnsX" very slow for teradata 13.10

Tags: teradata

I encountered a strange problem when I execute `select * from dbc.columnsX` on teradata 13.10. It is very slow; but on teradata 12.0 it is very fast. For teradata 13.10, does the dbc user lack some rights or there are some other reasons lead to this phenomena.

I know columnsX is X view.

Comment: What does "very slow" and "very fast" mean?  Also, are you comparing two identical Teradata systems perhaps becasue of an upgrade?

Comment: Given the complexities of the X views, is it possible on Teradata 12 that stats were collected and on Teradata 13.10 those stats are either missing or out of date? Are you managing access using roles or at the user level?

Comment: I mean "very slow" is there is hang phenamon but "very fast" is not, in addition it is not an upgrade just testing on two versions DB.

Comment: columnX is about 10556 rows queried from Teradata 12.0, what do you mean the stats and if those stats missing or out of date how can I recollect.

Comment: Do you have access to Viewpoint to observe what is occurring on the system when you are trying to query DBC.CoulmnsX? Can you query DBC.Columns instead for comparison? Is this a production server or Teradata Express?

Comment: Yes, I used Teradata SQL Assistant to executed above queries, query DBC.ColumnsX will hang and the progress is 0% but query DBC.Columns will show resultset quickly.

Comment: Do you have access to Viewpoint and the Query Monitor or My Queries portlet? I'm flying blind here trying to help you pinpoint the problem. Debugging the problem from SQL Assistant alone will be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered the same problem and Teradata sent us replacements of x views.

Here is the script for DBC.ColumnsX:

```
REPLACE VIEW DBC.ColumnsX
AS
SELECT CAST(TRANSLATE(dbase.DatabaseName USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE
                      WITH ERROR) AS CHAR(30)) (NAMED DatabaseName),
       CAST(TRANSLATE(tvm.tvmname USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR)
            AS CHAR(30)) (NAMED TableName),
       CAST(TRANSLATE(tvfields.fieldname USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR)
            AS CHAR(30)) (NAMED ColumnName),
       CAST(tvfields.fieldformat AS CHAR(30)) (NAMED ColumnFormat),
       CAST(tvfields.fieldtitle AS VARCHAR(60)) (NAMED ColumnTitle),
       tvfields.SPParameterType(NAMED SPParameterType),
       tvfields.fieldtype(NAMED ColumnType),
       CAST(TRANSLATE(tvfields.UDTName USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR)
            AS CHAR(30))(NAMED ColumnUDTName),
       tvfields.maxlength(NAMED ColumnLength,FORMAT 'Z,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9'),
       tvfields.DefaultValue,
       tvfields.Nullable,
       tvfields.CommentString,
       tvfields.TotalDigits(NAMED DecimalTotalDigits,FORMAT 'Z9'),
       tvfields.ImpliedPoint(NAMED DecimalFractionalDigits,FORMAT 'Z9'),
       tvfields.FieldId(NAMED ColumnId),
       tvfields.UpperCaseFlag,
       tvfields.Compressible,
       NULL(NAMED CompressValue),
       TRANSLATE(tvfields.ColumnCheck USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR)
       (NAMED ColumnConstraint),
       tvfields.CheckCount (NAMED ConstraintCount),
       CAST(TRANSLATE(DB1.DatabaseName USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR)
            AS CHAR(30)) (named CreatorName),
       tvfields.CreateTimeStamp,
       CAST(TRANSLATE(DB2.DatabaseName USING UNICODE_TO_LOCALE WITH ERROR)
            AS CHAR(30)) (named LastAlterName),
       tvfields.LastAlterTimeStamp,
       tvfields.CharType,
       tvfields.IdColType,
       tvfields.AccessCount,
       tvfields.LastAccessTimeStamp,
       tvfields.CompressValueList,
       tvfields.TimeDimension,
       tvfields.VTCheckType,
       tvfields.TTCheckType
FROM DBC.tvfields
         LEFT OUTER JOIN DBC.Dbase DB1
                      ON DBC.tvfields.CreateUID = DB1.DatabaseID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN DBC.Dbase DB2
                      ON DBC.tvfields.LastAlterUID = DB2.DatabaseID,
     DBC.dbase, DBC.TVM
WHERE  tvm.DatabaseId = dbase.DatabaseId
AND    tvm.tvmid = tvfields.tableid
AND   (tvm.tvmid IN
       (/* IDs of tables accessible to the USER */
       SELECT tvm.tvmid
        FROM   TVM, DBASE, ACCESSRIGHTS
        WHERE    tvm.tvmid <> '000000000000'xb
        AND      dbase.DataBaseNameI = USER
        AND      (
                   /* User has right on all in TVMs DB */
                   (tvm.DatabaseId = accessrights.DatabaseId AND
                   accessrights.tvmid = '000000000000'xb AND
                   accessrights.UserId = dbase.DatabaseId)
                 OR
                   /* TVMs DB has right granted to *PUBLIC*  */
                   (tvm.DatabaseId = accessrights.DatabaseId AND
                   accessrights.tvmid = '000000000000'xb AND
                   accessrights.Userid = '00000300'xb)
                 )
        union
        SELECT tvm.tvmid
        FROM   TVM, DBASE, ACCESSRIGHTS
        WHERE    tvm.tvmid <> '000000000000'xb
        AND      dbase.DataBaseNameI = USER
        AND      (
                   /* User has right on this specific TVM */
                   (tvm.tvmid = accessrights.tvmid AND
                   accessrights.UserId=dbase.DatabaseId)
                 OR
                   /* Specific TVM has right granted to *PUBLIC* */
                   (tvm.tvmid = accessrights.tvmid AND
                   accessrights.UserId= '00000300'xb )
                 )
        union
        SELECT tvm.tvmid
        FROM   TVM, DBASE, OWNERS
        WHERE    tvm.tvmid <> '000000000000'xb
        AND      dbase.DataBaseNameI = USER
        AND
                   /* User owns TVMs DB */
                   (tvm.DatabaseId = owners.owneeid AND
                   owners.ownerid = dbase.DatabaseId)
        union
        SELECT tvm.tvmid
        FROM   TVM , DBASE
        WHERE    tvm.tvmid <> '000000000000'xb
        AND      dbase.DataBaseNameI = USER
        AND
                   /* User *IS* TVMs DB */
                   (tvm.DatabaseId = dbase.DatabaseId)
        )
       OR tvm.tvmid IN
       (/* IDs of tables accessible to USER's roles */
        SELECT tvm.tvmid
        FROM   TVM, ACCESSRIGHTS, ROLES
        WHERE  TVM.tvmid       <> '000000000000'xb
        AND    Roles.RoleId    =  AccessRights.UserId
        AND    ROLE IS NOT NULL
        AND    AccessRights.UserId IN
               (SELECT RoleAccr.RoleId
                FROM   DBC.Roles RoleAccr)
        AND    (
                 /* Role has right on all in TVMs DB */
                 (tvm.DatabaseId      = accessrights.DatabaseId AND
                  accessrights.tvmid  = '000000000000'xb)
               )
        AND    (
                (UPPER(ROLE) <> 'ALL'  AND
                  /* Restrict to rights granted to current role */
                  /* and the roles nested within current role   */
                   (Roles.RoleId =
                    (SELECT CurRole.RoleId
                     FROM   DBC.Roles CurRole
                     WHERE  CurRole.RoleNameI = ROLE)
                    OR
                    Roles.RoleId  IN
                     (SELECT RG.RoleId
                      FROM   DBC.RoleGrants RG,
                             DBC.Roles      CurRole
                      WHERE  RG.GranteeId = CurRole.RoleId AND
                             CurRole.RoleNameI = ROLE))
                )
                OR
                (UPPER(ROLE) = 'ALL'  AND
                  /* The current role is ALL. Restrict to rights from */
                  /* the roles directly granted to current user and   */
                  /* nested roles within them */
                  (Roles.RoleId  IN
                   (SELECT UsrRG.RoleId
                    FROM   DBC.RoleGrants UsrRG,
                           DBC.Dbase      UserDB
                    WHERE  UsrRG.GranteeId = UserDB.DatabaseId AND
                           UserDB.DatabaseNameI = USER)
                   OR
                   Roles.RoleId  IN
                   (SELECT  RG.RoleId
                    FROM    DBC.RoleGrants RG
                    WHERE   RG.GranteeId in
                            (SELECT UsrRG.RoleId
                             FROM   DBC.RoleGrants UsrRG,
                                    DBC.Dbase      UserDB
                             WHERE  UsrRG.GranteeId = UserDB.DatabaseId AND
                                    UserDB.DatabaseNameI = USER)))
                )
               )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tvm.tvmid
        FROM   TVM, ACCESSRIGHTS, ROLES
        WHERE  TVM.tvmid       <> '000000000000'xb
        AND    Roles.RoleId    =  AccessRights.UserId
        AND    ROLE IS NOT NULL
        AND    AccessRights.UserId IN
               (SELECT RoleAccr.RoleId
                FROM   DBC.Roles RoleAccr)
        AND    (
                 /* Role has right on this specific TVM */
                 (tvm.tvmid           = accessrights.tvmid)
               )
        AND    (
                (UPPER(ROLE) <> 'ALL'  AND
                  /* Restrict to rights granted to current role */
                  /* and the roles nested within current role   */
                   (Roles.RoleId =
                    (SELECT CurRole.RoleId
                     FROM   DBC.Roles CurRole
                     WHERE  CurRole.RoleNameI = ROLE)
                    OR
                    Roles.RoleId  IN
                     (SELECT RG.RoleId
                      FROM   DBC.RoleGrants RG,
                             DBC.Roles      CurRole
                      WHERE  RG.GranteeId = CurRole.RoleId AND
                             CurRole.RoleNameI = ROLE))
                )
                OR
                (UPPER(ROLE) = 'ALL'  AND
                  /* The current role is ALL. Restrict to rights from */
                  /* the roles directly granted to current user and   */
                  /* nested roles within them */
                  (Roles.RoleId  IN
                   (SELECT UsrRG.RoleId
                    FROM   DBC.RoleGrants UsrRG,
                           DBC.Dbase      UserDB
                    WHERE  UsrRG.GranteeId = UserDB.DatabaseId AND
                           UserDB.DatabaseNameI = USER)
                   OR
                   Roles.RoleId  IN
                   (SELECT  RG.RoleId
                    FROM    DBC.RoleGrants RG
                    WHERE   RG.GranteeId in
                            (SELECT UsrRG.RoleId
                             FROM   DBC.RoleGrants UsrRG,
                                    DBC.Dbase      UserDB
                             WHERE  UsrRG.GranteeId = UserDB.DatabaseId AND
                                    UserDB.DatabaseNameI = USER)))
                )
               )
        )
      ) WITH CHECK OPTION;
```